# Firebase-allow users access only their own data

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am making a firebase Todo app in android (I'm a beginner). My problemis that every task made, no matter what user made it, is available for every user to see. I want to make it that every user can only read/write their own notes but all the rules I found and tried so far made it that no notes are sent to the database at all or are not shown.
The database with two users and the two notes:

[image]

User created

```
fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Error" + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

Note Creation:

(Not on the same page)

```
 btnSaveTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
            public void onClick (View v){
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ToDoApp").child(uid);

            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              //                        
                  
                dataSnapshot.child(udi).child("titletodo").setValue(titletodo.getText().toString());
                        
                dataSnapshot.getRef().child("titletodo").setValue(titletodo.getText().toString());
                        
                dataSnapshot.getRef().child("desctodo").setValue(desctodo.getText().toString());
                        
                      
                 dataSnapshot.getRef().child("datetodo").setValue(datetodo.getText().toString());
                        dataSnapshot.getRef().child("keytodo").setValue(keytodo);
                        Intent a = new Intent(AddTask.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.rl), "No Data.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            });
        }
    });
```

I've tried solutions from similar rules like this:

```
  "rules": {
    "ToDoApp": {
        "$userId": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $userId",
            ".write": "auth.uid == $userId",
        }
    }
}
```

}

I get No Data.

I would like to make it so that every user can only see, edit and delete notes that they made themselves.

Comment: I recommend that you start learning about security rules in the documentation.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer.I have seen this documentation and tried the rules but non of them is working I get database error and the data is not sent!

Comment: If you have non-working rules, I suggest copying them into your question so we can see where you might be going wrong.  Don't just copy the default rules - show that you've made an attempt.

Comment: Agreed with Doug here: without seeing the rules you tried, it'll be hard to help you better than this documentation page that covers the specific scenario of allowing users access to their own data: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security

Comment: I edited the post.Thanks for trying to help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get No Data"? Please be specific about the result of the query.  I s there an error, or is the snapshot just empty?

Comment: It's just empty and I can't create new todo task.